# How to get MVC 5.1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I installed Visual studio update 1 but now I can't install MVC 5.1
Please help me how can i install it ?
somewhere I read an article that you said we must to check box for Include Prerelease for NuGet
But I can't find this check box in NuGet Package
Please help me where is this Check box and how can I install Mvc 5.1 and other new Update for Visual studio

Comment: which version of VS you have? 2012 or 2013?

Comment: why you can't? MVC 5.1 is in release mode so simply type Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc on you package console

Answer (score 2):

The final release was done last week (the 17th of Jan), you should just be able to update to the latest version.

> `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`

Or explicitly request the version in the Package Manager Console by typing:

> `Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`
>
> `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.1.0`

Or if you haven't installed it yet, you can just call `Install-package` since that will use the latest version if none is specified.

> `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`